# Creating table with different row dimensions

Tags: r, row, dimensions

Let's say I got a table like this:

```
data <- c(1,2,3,6,5,6,9,"LC","LC","HC","HC","LC","HC","ALL")
attr(data,"dim") <- c(7,2)
data
     [,1] [,2] 
[1,] "1"  "LC" 
[2,] "2"  "LC" 
[3,] "3"  "HC" 
[4,] "6"  "HC" 
[5,] "5"  "LC" 
[6,] "6"  "HC" 
[7,] "9"  "ALL"
```

Now I want to manipulate the data so it looks like this:

```
     [,"LC"] [,"HC"] [,"ALL"] 
[1,] "1"     "3"     "9"
[2,] "2"     "6"
[3,] "5"     "6"
```

Is there a way to do this in **R** or is it just impossible and should I try another way of getting access to my data?

Comment: `data.frame` and `matrix` (and `array`) have a predefined shape (`n*m`). Just putting it out there more explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get very close by using `split`. This returns a list with the values you wanted and you can then use `lapply` or any other list manipulation function:

```
split(data[, 1], data[, 2])

$ALL
[1] "9"

$HC
[1] "3" "6" "6"

$LC
[1] "1" "2" "5"
```

If you must have the output in matrix format, then I suggest you pad the short vectors with NA:

```
x <- split(data[, 1], data[, 2])
n <- max(sapply(x, length))

pad_with_na <- function(x, n, padding=NA){
  c(x, rep(padding, n-length(x)))
}

sapply(x, pad_with_na, n)
```

This results in:

```
     ALL HC  LC 
[1,] "9" "3" "1"
[2,] NA  "6" "2"
[3,] NA  "6" "5"
```

Comment: that first split function is exactly what i was looking for. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE DATA

I prefere to read data into data.frame as it check if vectors are of equal length.

```
data <- data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,6,5,6,9), 
                   Y=c("LC","LC","HC","HC","LC","HC","ALL"))
```

CODE

```
data <- unstack(data, form=X~Y)# easier to read than split
Nmax <- do.call(max, lapply(data,length))
sapply(data, "[", seq(Nmax))# "borrowed" from other answer in SO
```